# Specific W10 Registry key for start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry, group-policy

Trying to deploy a custom start menu layout via GPO. However my org has limited the tile sizes to 2x2 and I want to use 4x4.
I've had a rummage around the registry but haven't had much luck and also manually changing the XML generated from Export-StartLayout to 4x4 just seems to break it entirely.
Anybody know where I can find the registry key for this setting?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this website](https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=15443). The registry keys for the start menu layout are located in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{479D4524-9CAF-40ED-8DB3-9801F051641B}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
```